# Finding the distribution of a card game where replacement happens until you recieve the card you want

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, card-games

Here is a card game. At the beginning of the game, you choose what rank of card you will be taking. Every round, 5 cards are dealt. Any that match the rank you chose are kept, the rest are shuffled back into the deck before the next round. You win when you get 3 cards of the chosen rank.

*What is the distribution for how many turns it takes to win?*

At first I was looking at a binomial distribution for each deal, but I am unsure how to account for the removal of successful card draws.

---

Here's my working so far: Let's imagine I choose rank 5 as the card I want and we only need 2 of them to win. If we assume a binomial distribution and we want to work out the odds of winning on round 2. Is it right to assume 2 hands of 5 cards = 1 hand of 10 cards? Below, for 10 cards we have

$$P(X\ge2)=1-P(X = 0)-P(X=1) =1-\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{10}}{\binom{52}{10}}-\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{10}}\approx0.481$$

This assumes the 2nd hand dealt is independent of the 1st, which I don't think is true. So, alternatively, if we look at a hand of 5 on its own and note down some probabilities:
$$P(Y=0)=\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{52}{5}}\approx0.659$$
$$P(Y=1)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{5}}\approx0.299$$
Then,
$$P(Y\ge2)=P(Y_1=0,\, Y_2\ge2\,\,||\,\,Y_1=1,\, Y_2\ge1\,\,||\,\,Y_1\ge2)$$
(Where $Y_1$ indicates the $1^{st}$ deal, $Y_2$ the $2^{nd}$)
$$=0.659\cdot(1-0.659-0.299)+0.299\cdot(1-\frac{\binom{3}{0}\binom{48}{5}}{\binom{51}{5}})+1-0.659-0.299$$
$$\approx0.028+0.299\cdot0.271+0.042\approx0.151$$

These are vastly different results so I figure I've gone wrong somewhere, but I can't see it

Comment: If you choose rank $5$ and the first deal has $\{7h,Js,5c,2h,8d\}$, then you keep the $5c$ and *four* cards are dealt replace the unwanted cards. Is this correct?

Comment: No, the *5c* is kept (lets say its put in its own pile), and 5 new cards are dealt.

Comment: Then the unwanted cards are simply discarded, not replaced. (Replacement implies a one-to-one exchange.)

Comment: So is it fair to assume that 2 hands of 5 cards each wil have the same distribution as 1 hand of 10 cards?

Comment: I think I missed a key point. The unwated cards, ${7h, Js, 2h, 8d}$ are shuffled back into the deck before dealing the new hand.

Comment: Yes, and that may be the best approach. You have miscalculated: $1-\frac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{10}}{\binom{52}{10}}-\frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{9}}{\binom{52}{10}}\approx0.1625$ and this the probability of winning on either the first *or* the second round.

Comment: Shuffling the unwanted back into the deck does make a big difference. You cannot then consider a hand of ten.